# Expression: cannot dereference value-initialized map/set iterator (Debug Assertion Failed!)

Tags: c++, insert, iterator, mutex, erase

The simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<int, uint64_t> mp;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 9);

//std::mutex _mutex;
//std::shared_timed_mutex _mutex;
std::shared_mutex _mutex;

void t1()
{
    int key = 0;
    uint64_t i;
    while (1)
    {
        ++key;
        if (key < 1000)
        {
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.find(key);
            if (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "UPDATE\t1\t" << it_mp->first << "\t" << it_mp->second << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                it_mp->second = i;
            }
            else
            {
                std::unique_lock guard(_mutex);

                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "INSERT\t1\t" << key << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                mp.insert({ key, i });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i = distr(gen);
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.begin();
            while (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                if (it_mp->second == i)
                {
                    std::unique_lock guard(_mutex);

                    std::cout << "ERASE\t1\t" << it_mp->first << "\t<-\t" << i << "\n";
                    it_mp = mp.erase(it_mp);
                }
                else
                {
                    ++it_mp;
                }
            }

            key = 0;
        }
    }
}

void t2()
{
    int key = 0;
    uint64_t i;
    while (1)
    {
        ++key;
        if (key < 1000)
        {
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.find(key);
            if (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "UPDATE\t2\t" << it_mp->first << "\t" << it_mp->second << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                it_mp->second = i;
            }
            else
            {
                std::unique_lock guard(_mutex);

                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "INSERT\t2\t" << key << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                mp.insert({ key, i });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i = distr(gen);
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.begin();
            while (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                if (it_mp->second == i)
                {
                    std::unique_lock guard(_mutex);

                    std::cout << "ERASE\t2\t" << it_mp->first << "\t<-\t" << i << "\n";
                    it_mp = mp.erase(it_mp);
                }
                else
                {
                    ++it_mp;
                }
            }

            key = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread _t1(t1);
    _t1.detach();

    std::thread _t2(t2);
    _t2.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

An exception occurs at an arbitrary point in time (Error in caption).
Is there a way to make this code work with minimal effort?

I am looking for a method to concurrently communicate with std::map in a multithreaded environment. But, Debug Assertion Failed: Expression: cannot dereference value-initialized map/set iterator.

Comment: Why is `t2` a thread? Creating a thread and then directly joining it doesn't make sense. If you want to execute `t1` and `t2` in parallel then it's enough that *one* of them is a separate thread, like `t1`. Then you just plain call `t2`.

Comment: And you use the map without locking or synchronization, so there are data-races. Which means your code will have *undefined behavior*. You need to protect *all* access to the map.

Comment: This is a generalized little piece of a very large code. I must have thousands of such threads.

Comment: I try use std::unique_lock guard(_mutex); ... without luck, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and checking what causes the exception? Shouldn't you lock the map when you do an update? And shouldn't you be locking the map earlier in the other operations? What would happen, for example, if you find a key and try to erase it but another thread erases it first?

Comment: Infinite loop with no side effect: undefined behavior. I don't know when your loop stops. That's a very bad start.  
`std::map` isn't thread safe. Start by reading about [memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Formal_description) 
To answer the question: No. There is no way to make that code work with minimal[sic] effort. I'm not sure there is a way at all. It would be faster to rewrite it with thread-safety in mind from the begining.

Comment: Are t1 and t2 identical?

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.find(key);
```

This accesses the contents of the multimap, without the protection of a mutex. The other execution thread is modifying this map, concurrently. This is undefined behavior.

Neither `std::map`, nor any other container in the C++ library, is thread-safe. This means that ***all*** access to the container, and ***not just modifications to the container***, must be synchronized (i.e., protected by a mutex). The shown code locks a mutex to synchronize only certain modifications to the map. This is insufficient. ***All*** access to the map must be synchronized.

Additionally, ignoring the subject of synchronization for a brief moment: the overall algorithm also has another flaw. Even if `find()` does not find an existing value in the map, the other execution thread may end up reaching the same conclusion and `insert()` its value into the map before the first execution thread gets around to calling `insert()`, itself. The clear intent of the shown code is for the find/insert to be an atomic operation. This is another reason why that entire section of code must be protected by a mutex (and not only the `insert()` call).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are right. *Mutexes need before iterators*.

**shared_lock** before "update" and "insertion", **unique_lock** before "erase".

Refurbished code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <shared_mutex>

std::map<int, uint64_t> mp;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 9);

//std::mutex _mutex;
//std::shared_timed_mutex _mutex;
//std::recursive_mutex _mutex;

std::shared_mutex _mutex;

void t1()
{
    int key = 0;
    uint64_t i;
    while (1)
    {
        ++key;
        if (key < 1000)
        {
            std::shared_lock guard(_mutex);
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.find(key);
            if (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "UPDATE\t1\t" << it_mp->first << "\t" << it_mp->second << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                it_mp->second = i;
            }
            else
            {
                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "INSERT\t1\t" << key << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                mp.insert ({key, i});
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i = distr(gen);
            std::unique_lock guard(_mutex);
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.begin();
            while (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                if (it_mp->second == i)
                {
                    std::cout << "ERASE\t1\t" << it_mp->first << "\t<-\t" << i << "\n";
                    it_mp = mp.erase(it_mp);
                }
                else
                {
                    ++it_mp;
                }
            }

            key = 0;
        }
    }
}

void t2()
{
    int key = 0;
    uint64_t i;
    while (1)
    {
        ++key;
        if (key < 1000)
        {
            std::shared_lock guard(_mutex);
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.find(key);
            if (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "UPDATE\t2\t" << it_mp->first << "\t" << it_mp->second << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                it_mp->second = i;
            }
            else
            {
                i = distr(gen);
                std::cout << "INSERT\t2\t" << key << "\t->\t" << i << "\n";
                mp.insert({ key, i });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i = distr(gen);
            std::unique_lock guard(_mutex);
            std::map<int, uint64_t>::iterator it_mp = mp.begin();
            while (it_mp != mp.end())
            {
                if (it_mp->second == i)
                {
                    std::cout << "ERASE\t2\t" << it_mp->first << "\t<-\t" << i << "\n";
                    it_mp = mp.erase(it_mp);
                }
                else
                {
                    ++it_mp;
                }
            }

            key = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread _t1(t1);
    _t1.detach();

    std::thread _t2(t2);
    _t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

... works like charm. ... Maybe this will help someone.